# Stop F8 key from launching Music (the new iTunes)

Tags: macos, keyboard, catalina, music.app

(macOS 10.15.7 on MacBook Pro 13" 2020 Intel-based)

I would like to keep using the F-keys as standard function keys (without the need of pressing `fn` at the same time). I even want to keep the general Play/Pause function of F8. I just want to stop F8 from launching the application Music. Is it possible?

Comment: There's a similar question about overriding Mac media keys [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/430792/stop-f8-key-from-launching-music-the-new-itunes)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need/use Apple Music, you can install [noTunes](https://github.com/tombonez/noTunes) to stop it from launching, note that this stops you from even opening it manually. You will also need to set it to start on login.

Answer (score 0):

The exact method may differ between MacBook models and macOS versions, but generally, the option to swap function key behavior is in “keyboard” pane of system preferences.  More specific instructions in [this apple support document.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht204436)